# Is it possible to add selected content of dynamic select list to a new table?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a database with the name ***'ecc'***.

The database has a table with the name ***'task'***.

The table task has three fields named as ***'assignedto'*** ***'subject' 'date'***.

Appropriate Data type for date is used.

***'assignedto'*** field must content the selected content of select list.

***'subject'*** is simply a text field.

***'date'*** field should contain date in ***'yyyy/mm/dd'*** formate.

The content of select list is extracted from table ***'client'***  of field 
***'ProjectManager'*** from same ***'ecc'*** database.

My issue withe the below code is:- It is not inserting the selected content of select list into table 'task' in field ***'assignedto'*** following fields ***'subject'*** and ***'date'***.

It is showing me few warnings related to ***if(isset($_post(''))***.

If i don't use ***if(isset($_post(''))*** the it is showing me warning for undeclared variable.

The warnings are:-

1)Notice: Undefined index: $mysqli in C:\wamp\www\select.php on line 53

2)Notice: Undefined index: subject in C:\wamp\www\select.php on line 57

3)Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\wamp\www\select.php on line 58

```
<?php
// Connect db
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ecc');

// check if error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Can not connect to DB error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. 
$mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo "Select client";

// MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProjectManager FROM client");

echo '<select name="project_manager">';
echo '<option value="">-select project manager-</option>';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option 
value="'.$row['ProjectManager'].'">'.$row['ProjectManager'].'</option>';
}  
echo '</select>';

// Frees memory

$results->free();

?>



<html>
<body>
<form action = "select.php" method ="POST">


  Subject:<br>

  <input type="text" name="subject"><br>

  <br>

    <input type = "date" name = "date"><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">  


</form>
</body>
</html>



<?php

$assignedto = $_POST['$mysqli'];



    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];




$sql="INSERT INTO task (assignedto,
                        subject,
                        date)
                        VALUES('$assignedto','$subject',
                        '$date')";


if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    echo 'record added';
}

else
{
    echo 'record not added';
}
//header("refresh:02;url=index.html");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your query to use prepared statements also used mysqli real_escape string.. this somewhat help you prevent sql injection.. you should always use that.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action = "select.php" method ="POST">

    <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ecc');
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Can not connect to DB error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '.$mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Select client";
    if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProjectManager FROM client"))
    {?>
    <select name="project_manager">
    <option value="">-select project manager-</option>
    <?php

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?><option value="<?php echo $row['ProjectManager'] ?>"><?php echo $row['ProjectManager'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }  
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php $results->free(); }?>
      Subject:<br>

      <input type="text" name="subject"><br>

      <br>

        <input type = "date" name = "date"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">  


    </form>
    </body>
    </html>



    <?php
    if(  isset($_POST['project_manager']) && isset($_POST['subject'])  && isset($_POST['date']) ){
        print_r($_POST);
        $assignedto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_manager']);
        $subject = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['subject']);
        $date =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);


        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO task (assignedto,subject,date) VALUES(?,?,?)")){
            $stmt->bind_param('sss',$assignedto,$subject,$date);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows_affected = $stmt->affected_rows;
            if($rows_affected >0){
               echo "inserted successfully";    
            }elseif($rows_affected === -1){
               echo 'there is an error inserting';    
            }elseif($rows_affected === NULL){
               echo "invalid argument supplied";    
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In form you have only two values one is date and another one is subject you dont have anything like mysqli..

```
 $assignedto = $_POST['$mysqli'];
```

shows warning because there is no $mysqli name.

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
```

will also show error because it will be posted only when you submit the form.. so you have to put inside

```
if(isset($_POST['date'] && isset($_POST['subject'] && isset($_POST['assingedto'])
```

the following line

```
$sql="INSERT INTO task (assignedto,
                    subject,
                    date)
                    VALUES('$assignedto','$subject',
                    '$date')";
```

has error even if you submit the form you are submitting with only two values. you dont have value for assignedto...

Comment: I made the changes as you stated above but still data is not added in backend @v Sugumar

Comment: value for '$assignedto' should be the selected content of select list. the content of select list is extracted from table 'client' of field 'ProjectManager' @v Sugumar

Comment: then select should be inside form and name should be assignedto and change $assignedto = $_POST['$mysqli'];  to $assignedto = $_POST['assignedto'];

Comment: Would you please rewrite and post that part of the code @v Sugumar

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Connect db
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ecc');

// check if error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Can not connect to DB error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo "Select client";

// MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProjectManager FROM client");

echo '<form action = "select.php" method = "post"><select name="assignedto"></form>';
echo '<option value="">-select project manager-</option>';

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProjectManager'].'">'.$row['ProjectManager'].'</option>';
}  
echo '</select>';

// Frees memory

$results->free();

?>



<html>
<body>
<form action = "select.php" method ="POST">

<br>
  Subject:<br>

  <input type="text" name="subject"><br>

  <br>
  Date:
    <input type = "date" name = "date" value = "yyyy/mm/dd"><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">  


</form>
</body>
</html>



<?php

    $assignedto = $_POST['assignedto'];
    if(isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['assingedto'])){


    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];




$sql="INSERT INTO task (assignedto,
                        subject,
                        date)
                        VALUES('$assignedto','$subject',
                        '$date')";


if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    echo 'record added';
}

else
{
    echo 'record not added';
}
//header("refresh:02;url=index.html");
    }
?>
```

@v Sugumar i amd all the changes have a look at it 
but still it's showing an error

Notice: Undefined index: assignedto in C:\wamp\www\select.php on line 54